# Encrypted twitter feed

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

I'm developing an iOS application , that will take a twits from twitter,
I'm using the following **API**

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&count=2&screen_name=TareqAlSuwaidan

The problem are feed in Arabic Language ,
i.e the text feed appears like this

**\u0623\u0646\u0643 \u0648\u0627\u0647\u0645**

How can i get the real text (or how to encode this to get real text) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not encrypted, it is unicode. The codes 0600 - 06ff is Arabic. NSString handles unicode.

Here is an example:

```
NSString *string = @"\u0623\u0646\u0643 \u0648\u0627\u0647\u0645";
NSLog(@"string: '%@'", string);
```

NSLog output:

> string: 'أنك واهم'

The only question is exactly what problem are you seeing, are you getting the Arabic text? Are you using `NSJSONSerialization` to deserialize the `JSON`? If so there should be no problem.

Here is an example with the question URL (don't use synchronous requests in production code):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&count=2&screen_name=TareqAlSuwaidan"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSDictionary *object1 = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *text = [object1 objectForKey:@"text"];
NSLog(@"text: '%@'", text);
```

NSLog output:

```
text: '@Naser_Albdya أيدت الثورة السورية منذ بدايتها وارجع لليوتوب واكتب( سوريا السويدان )
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are Unicode literals. I *think* all that's needed is to use `NSString`'s `stringWithUTF8String:` method on the string you have. That should use `NSString`'s native Unicode handling to convert the literals to the actual characters. Example:

```
NSString *directFromTwitter = [twitterInterface getTweet];
// directFromTwitter contains "\u0623\u0646\u0643 \u0648\u0627\u0647\u0645"
NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[directFromTwitter UTF8String]];
// encodedString contains "أنك واهم", or something like it
```

The method call inside the conversion call (`[directFromTwitter UTF8String]`) is to get access to the raw bytes of the string, that are used by `stringWithUTF8String`. I'm not exactly sure on what those code points come out to, I just relied on Python to do the conversion.